# Django Rest API - django-rest-auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-auth

[image: error]

[image: pipfile]

[image]
I have installed `django-rest-auth` package in pipenv. But getting this error

Comment: Can you please show your installed apps in your config

Comment: @hendrikschneider added it.

Comment: There is a comma missing after 'rest_auth'

Comment: Lmao man..why is django so hard...thank you so much.

Comment: Would you mind to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSTALLED_APPS needs to be a list. You are missing a comma between "rest_auth" and "profiles". Therefore, a module "rest_authprofiles" is being imported.